# Generate python UNIX timestamp

Tags: python, unix-timestamp, binance, kraken.com

I am working with the kraken and binance APIs. The binance API returns a time like this: `1612722603026` inside of the API response. The kraken API does not return a time for the API response so I am trying to generate a timestamp to match the one from binance in terms of format/units (UNIX). I tried using `int(time.time())` but the result of this is: `1612722603` which when I convert to a date [here](https://dencode.com/date) gives me the date: `1970-01-19T15:58:42.602Z` How can I generate a UNIX timestamp in python (one that matches the one from binance)? It seems to me that the one I am generating is 3 digits short

Comment: One is in seconds, the other in milliseconds.

Comment: Ok that makes sense! Thanks!